# JUnit5 Console Progress Status

Tags: junit5

I recently migrated my JUnit framework from 4.12 to 5.1.0 and noticed a minor issue. Was wondering if someone could help me get this sorted.

When I was using JUnit 4 with Gradle, I could see the Progress status of the test and the current test that was being executed when the tests were run in Console.

However, when I use JUnit5 and it's runners, I get the final completion report in a tree structure, which is amazing, But i'm missing my old console report where I could see the progress status with the current run being executed.

Is there a way to setup this using the JUnit5 setup?

Answer (score 1):

Since  version 4.6 Gradle has built-in JUnit 5 support which will provide standard progress status. The support however is still missing out on a few important features, see e.g. https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4605